# Virtualizing Windows on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, windows, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu server on my local server and need to virtualize Windows on it, so that the developers can access this instance of Windows OS at their end.

Does anyone have any documentation or suggestions to help out a first-time virtualizer?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you may try installing something like VirtualBox or VMWare.

Take a look at [this list of solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software) to figure out what covers your need.

The above are full virtual machines. If you only need to run Windows programs on the Linux server, you may want to check out [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Qemu/KVM, libvirt, and virt-manager are also probably worth mentioning here as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to run virtual machine with Windows inside, besides VirtualBox or VMWare you can try [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO) .